# ReferenceError: ToolBar in not defined, how do I resolve?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

Started a new nextjs project about three days ago. Just updated everything then added the following dependencies:

```
yarn add @material-ui/core
yarn add @mui/icons-material
yarn add @mui/material
```

Got this code:

```
import * as React from 'react';

// Material UI components
import AppBar from '@mui/material/AppBar';
import Box from '@mui/material/Box';
import Toolbar from '@mui/material/Toolbar';
import Typography from '@mui/material/Typography';
import Button from '@mui/material/Button';
import IconButton from '@mui/material/IconButton';
import MenuIcon from '@mui/icons-material';

export default function Header() {
    return (
        <AppBar position="static">
            <ToolBar>
                {/* Inside the IconButton, render various icons*/}
                <IconButton 
                    size="large"
                    edge="start"
                    color="inherit"
                    aria-label="menu"
                    sx={{ mr:2 }}
                >
                {/* This is a simple Menu Icon wrapped in Icon */}
                    <MenuIcon />
                </IconButton>
                {/* The Typography component applies default font weights and sizes */}
                
                <Typeography 
                    variant="h6"
                    component="div"
                    sx={{ flexGrow:1 }}
                    STRM-Sat Header
                >
                </Typeography>
                <Button color="inherit">Login</Button>
            </ToolBar>
        </AppBar>
    );
}
```

Initially I got an error about `@emotion/react` and `@emotion/styled` module not being found. They weren't apart of my project, but went ahead and installed them anyways.

```
ReferenceError: ToolBar is not defined
    at Header (webpack-internal:///./pages/api/header.js:37:90)
    at renderWithHooks (/mnt/c/Users/root/Desktop/satrange/sat/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js:5658:16)
    at renderIndeterminateComponent (/mnt/c/Users/root/Desktop/satrange/sat/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js:5731:15)        
    at renderElement (/mnt/c/Users/root/Desktop/satrange/sat/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js:5946:7)
    at renderNodeDestructiveImpl (/mnt/c/Users/root/Desktop/satrange/sat/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js:6104:11)
    at renderNodeDestructive (/mnt/c/Users/root/Desktop/satrange/sat/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js:6076:14)
    at renderNode (/mnt/c/Users/root/Desktop/satrange/sat/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js:6259:12)
    at renderChildrenArray (/mnt/c/Users/root/Desktop/satrange/sat/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js:6211:7)
    at renderNodeDestructiveImpl (/mnt/c/Users/root/Desktop/satrange/sat/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js:6141:7)
    at renderNodeDestructive (/mnt/c/Users/root/Desktop/satrange/sat/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js:6076:14)
ReferenceError: ToolBar is not defined
    at Header (webpack-internal:///./pages/api/header.js:37:90)
    at renderWithHooks (/mnt/c/Users/root/Desktop/satrange/sat/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js:5658:16)
    at renderIndeterminateComponent (/mnt/c/Users/root/Desktop/satrange/sat/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js:5731:15)        
    at renderElement (/mnt/c/Users/root/Desktop/satrange/sat/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js:5946:7)
    at renderNodeDestructiveImpl (/mnt/c/Users/root/Desktop/satrange/sat/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js:6104:11)
    at renderNodeDestructive (/mnt/c/Users/root/Desktop/satrange/sat/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js:6076:14)
    at renderNode (/mnt/c/Users/root/Desktop/satrange/sat/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js:6259:12)
    at renderChildrenArray (/mnt/c/Users/root/Desktop/satrange/sat/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js:6211:7)
    at renderNodeDestructiveImpl (/mnt/c/Users/root/Desktop/satrange/sat/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js:6141:7)
    at renderNodeDestructive (/mnt/c/Users/root/Desktop/satrange/sat/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js:6076:14)
error - pages/api/header.js (15:13) @ Header
error - ReferenceError: ToolBar is not defined       
    at Header (webpack-internal:///./pages/api/header.js:37:90)
    at renderWithHooks (/mnt/c/Users/root/Desktop/satrange/sat/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js:5658:16)
    at renderIndeterminateComponent (/mnt/c/Users/root/Desktop/satrange/sat/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js:5731:15)        
    at renderElement (/mnt/c/Users/root/Desktop/satrange/sat/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js:5946:7)
    at renderNodeDestructiveImpl (/mnt/c/Users/root/Desktop/satrange/sat/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js:6104:11)
    at renderNodeDestructive (/mnt/c/Users/root/Desktop/satrange/sat/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js:6076:14)
    at renderNode (/mnt/c/Users/root/Desktop/satrange/sat/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js:6259:12)
    at renderChildrenArray (/mnt/c/Users/root/Desktop/satrange/sat/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js:6211:7)
    at renderNodeDestructiveImpl (/mnt/c/Users/root/Desktop/satrange/sat/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js:6141:7)
    at renderNodeDestructive (/mnt/c/Users/root/Desktop/satrange/sat/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js:6076:14) {
  page: '/'
}
  13 |     return (
  14 |         <AppBar position="static">
> 15 |             <ToolBar>
     |             ^
  16 |                 {/* Inside the IconButton, render various icons*/}
  14 |         <AppBar position="static">
> 15 |             <ToolBar>
     |             ^
  16 |                 {/* Inside the IconButton, render various icons*/}  17 |                 <IconButton
  18 |                     size="large"
```

I'm following this site: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-create-header-in-react-js/ to build the most basic Header ever. Haven't found a solution because I'm still relatively new to this. Anyone have a clue what's going on and what its not defined if I've imported it already?

Comment: I have the feeling that the tutorial is not well written, to use exact same stuff you can follow AppBar demo: https://mui.com/material-ui/react-app-bar/

Comment: That's brilliant! I will give it a go and close this ticket if implementation is successful. Thank you!

Comment: @HiB Could it not be a case problem? You import Toolbar and use ToolBar

Comment: @0xRyN - would love to say possible, but I haven't a clue what that is. lol, super new at this.
```import Toolbar from '@mui/material/Toolbar';``` was used in to call the same object to the page. Interestingly, there is no difference in code except that it runs: ```<Box ...><Appbar ...><Toolbar>``` then closes out with just that, opposite order. I'm wondering if I needed to put it in a ```<div>``` then? Straight forwards fs, so I have no idea other then that last question could be the solution. I'll have to try it and see. Further still, ```<Box>``` might have been exactly what was missing.

Comment: ```<Box>``` being what's missing, and being the only change made.

```import Box from '@mui/material/Box'; import Toolbar from '@mui/material/Toolbar';```
```<Box><Appbar><Toolbar>{/* load of jargon/more code stuff */}</Toolbar></Appbar></Box>```

Comment: I edited my answer provided below with the information stated above. See for details.

Comment: @HiB You didn't understand me, the caps in `ToolBar` may have to do something with this. Instead of using `<ToolBar>`, use `<Toolbar>`. Javascript is case sensitive, and maybe the caps "B" is the reason the problem is happening.

Comment: @0xRyN - interestingly, that too was changed in the new code so you may be right. Wasn't paying attention to that, good eye! I've done the same in my answer without realizing. Thanks for the explanation :)

Comment: Just want to know, ifbthat is the case: seems odd that they'd cap the "B" for ```<AppBar>``` and not for ```<Toolbar>```. Dealers choice I guess, though I imagine a duplicate is possible with the right packages and not realizing like me.

Comment: @HiB I just checked the docs and that was it :) I wrote a full answer below, please mark it as solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[JavaScript is case-sensitive](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_syntax.asp#:%7E:text=All%20JavaScript%20identifiers%20are%20case%20sensitive.).

You wrote `<ToolBar>` instead of `<Toolbar>`, but React doesn't know what the `<ToolBar>` is, since you only import `Toolbar`.

According to [Material UI docs](https://mui.com/material-ui/api/toolbar/), it's `<Toolbar>` without caps while `AppBar` has uppercase B *for some reason*.

Just change `<ToolBar>` to `<Toolbar>` and you're done :)

Comment: Gotta be careful with that fosho. I'll notify the site owner of the issue as well. Appreciate the assistance.

Answer (score 0):

The above answer remains unsolved, tho I do believe @Mert Canatan, see above comments, was correct in his assertion. I was able to implement a working header after following this link: [mui.com/material-ui/react-app-bar](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-app-bar)

Technically not a solution, logically I believe the solution may be as follows:

```
{/* add Import Box*/}
Import Box from '@mui/material/Box';
```

Then, after return...

```
return (
<Box sx={{ flexGrow: 1 }}>
 <AppBar position="static">
  <Toolbar>
{*/ Fun Code and other shenanigans required */}
  </Toolbar>
 </AppBar>
</Box>
```

Follow link attached to see code advised vs code above.